# What is wrong with my constraint in my create table query?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL programming and having a problem with a constraint I'm setting up on the table named SP. I am using MySQLWorkbench and getting this error:

> Error Code: 1239. Incorrect foreign key definition for 'FK_SP_sNo': Key reference and table reference don't match

I don't see what's wrong with it. Can anybody please help and explain what's wrong?

Best regards

```
CREATE TABLE S 
(
    sNo CHAR(5), 
    sName CHAR(20), 
    status NUMERIC(5), 
    city CHAR(15),

    PRIMARY KEY (sNo)
);

CREATE TABLE P
(
    pNo CHAR(6), 
    pName CHAR(20), 
    color CHAR(20), 
    weight NUMERIC(10), 
    city CHAR(15),

    PRIMARY KEY (pNo)
);

CREATE TABLE SP
(
    sNo CHAR(5),
    pNo CHAR(6),
    qty SMALLINT, 

    PRIMARY KEY (sNo, pNo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SP_sNo FOREIGN KEY (sNo) REFERENCES S,
    CONSTRAINT FK_SP_pNo FOREIGN KEY (pNo) REFERENCES P 
);
```

Comment: `REFERENCES S(sNo)`, `REFERENCES P(pNo)`

Comment: You should add it as an answer @Eric

Answer (score 1):

You need the column name for the referenced table.

```
CREATE TABLE SP
(
sNo CHAR(5),
pNo CHAR(6),
qty SMALLINT, PRIMARY KEY (sNo, pNo),
CONSTRAINT FK_SP_sNo FOREIGN KEY (sNo) REFERENCES S(sNo),
CONSTRAINT FK_SP_pNo FOREIGN KEY (pNo) REFERENCES P(sNo) 
);
```

Comment: This is the standard way of declaring foreign keys. +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the same in MySQL, but in Microsoft SQL Server I would define a FK_SP_sNo foreign key like this:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_SP_sNo FOREIGN KEY (sNo) REFERENCES S(sNo)
```

The difference here is that the REFERENCES clause is in the form:

```
CONSTRAINT ConstraintName FOREIGN KEY (LocalField) REFERENCES RemoteTable(RemoteField)
```